# How do I correctly bind?

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

I have a class MyClass, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and it has some properties that must be bound in some page. In my page I have

```
private MyClass myclass;
```

and in the page constructor I write

```
ContentPanel.DataContext = myclass;
```

When I assign myclass to some MyClass object, which I get from some callback, nothing is shown in page.

But when I write the properties that I must change instead of MyClass class in page.cs and bind them it work correctly. 
Or when I give

```
ContentPanel.DataContext = this;
```

and in xaml I write

```
{binding this.myclass.property}
```

it also works correctly.

Here is callback

```
 public void GetCommonInfoCallback(UserCommonInfo userCommonInfo)
    {
        CommonInfo = userCommonInfo;
    }
```

where UserCommonInfo is MyClass, and CommonInfo is myclass.

```
 private UserCommonInfo userCommonInfo ;
    public UserCommonInfo CommonInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return userCommonInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (userCommonInfo != value)
            {
                userCommonInfo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CommonInfo");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't understand where is my mistake. Can you help me?

Comment: We need to see more of the failing code.  Post a repro.

Comment: this is example of MyClass property rivate string username;
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                if (username != value)
                {
                    username = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Username");
                }
            }
        }

Comment: @ctacke  Please look I edited my question. And I tried different ways, here is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set DataContext, it is the specific instance of MyClass that is used for data binding. So after executing

```
ContentPanel.DataContext = myclass;
```

you could later execute

```
myclass.someProperty = "new value of someProperty";
```

and the data will be updated in the bound control (assuming this is not a OneTime binding, but OneWay or TwoWay binding instead).

If I understand you question correctly, you want to change the binding to use a different instance of MyClass.

```
myclass = new MyClass { /* ... */ }; // new instance of MyClass
```

At this point, the controls are still bound to the previous instance of MyClass. You can change that by updating the DataContext:

```
DataContext = myclass; // set context to the new MyClass instance
```

The second approach that you wrote, with

```
ContentPanel.DataContext = this;
```

represents a different style, where you are making the page class also serve as the data model instance for data binding.

In this case, you are not changing the data binding to use a new instance of the data model (the page instance, 'this', is not changing). IMHO, there is very valuable to separate the page and the data model, so I prefer to not use the DataContext = this approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks for answer. So you advise everytime to change Datacontext.

Comment: public void GetCommonInfoCallback(UserCommonInfo userCommonInfo)
    {
        CommonInfo = userCommonInfo;
        Datacontext = CommonInfo                                                                }

Comment: If the callback returns a new MyClass instance, then setting the DataContext to the new instance is the way to go. If you callback returned some individual values that can be set in the currently bound instance (the myclass.someProperty = ... example) then just set those properties directly on the existing data model (myclass) and then you do not set DataContext since it is already set to the correct instance.